# How to create sum of numbers from ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to sum a column of numbers but when I use code below, the "total" field is empty. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projectList.projects>   
    <td>{{project.description}}</td>
    <td>{{project.type.cost | currency}}</td>
</tr>

<h2>Total: {{ total() | currency }}</h2>
```

Javascript:

```
myApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function ProjectListCtrl(Projects) {
var projectList = this;
projectList.total = function(){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(projectList.projects, function(project) {
        total += project.type.cost;
    });
    return total;
};
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the `controllerAs` syntax, such that `ng-controller="ProjectListCtrl as projectList"`

With that, you need to call `projectList.total()` from the view instead of just `total()`

Comment: I feel foolish for missing that one. Thank you. I'm noticing, though, that I'm not getting the sum of the numbers. Instead the numbers are concatenated. E.g., if the original numbers are `30.00` and `20.00`, I'm getting `30,20.00` instead of `50.00` in the total column. Should I post a separate question related to this?

Comment: You don't have to post a separate question, your `cost` property must be a string.  Either make sure your service is returning actual numbers, e.g., `4` instead of `"4"` or cast the strings as numbers, i.e., `total += parseFloat(project.type.cost)` -- the preferable method would be to return the correct data type from your service, i.e., method 1